# I'm getting Segmentation fault when trying to make vectors in C++. How do I fix this?

Tags: c++, arrays, class, vector, segmentation-fault

I currently have an assignment to make a board game in C++. I'm currently facing a problem with vectors because it keeps giving me 'Segmentation fault'. I have put an arrow comment at the part of my code which I think is the problem, It is in the Map::DisplayMap() function. But, I do not know what to do to fix it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct Map
{
    vector<vector<char>> board;
    int DimX, DimY;

    void CellContent(int DimX, int DimY);
    void DisplayMap();
    int getDimensions();
};

void Map::CellContent(int DimX, int DimY)
{
    char objects[] = {' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'X', '#', '@', '$'};
    int noOfObjects = 10;

    board.resize(DimY); // Create empty vector
    for (int i = 0; i < DimY; ++i)
    {
        board[i].resize(DimX);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < DimY; ++i) // put random Characters inside vector
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < DimX; ++j)
        {
            int ObjectNumber = rand() % noOfObjects;
            board[i][j] = objects[ObjectNumber];
        }
    }
}

void Map::DisplayMap()
{
    cout << " --__--__--__--__--__--__--__--" << endl; // Header
    cout << " = Alien, defeat the Zombies! =" << endl;
    cout << " __--__--__--__--__--__--__--__" << endl;

    // Each Row
    for (int i = 0; i < DimY; ++i)
    {
        // DisplayMap upper border
        cout << "  ";
        for (int j = 0; j < DimX; ++j)
        {
            cout << "+-";
        }
        cout << "+" << endl;

        // DisplayMap row number
        cout << setw(2) << (DimY - i);

        // DisplayMap cell content
        for (int j = 0; j < DimX; ++j)
        {
            cout << "|" << board[i][j];// <========= The problem starts here, I think.
                // << " "; // letak content
        }
        cout << "|" << endl;
    }

    // DisplayMap lower border
    cout << "  ";
    for (int j = 0; j < DimX; ++j)
    {
        cout << "+-";
    }
    cout << "+" << endl;

    // DisplayMap column number
    cout << "  ";
    for (int i = 1; i <= DimX; ++i)
    {
        int digit;
        digit = i / 10;

        if (DimX >= 10)
        {
            cout << " ";
            if (digit == 0)
            {
                cout << " ";
            }
            else
            {
                cout << digit;
            }
        }
    }
    if (DimX >= 10)
    {
        cout << endl
             << "  ";
        for (int j = 1; j <= DimX; ++j)
        {
            cout << " " << (j % 10);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= DimX; ++j)
        {
            cout << " " << (j % 10);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    Map Map;
    Map.DimX = 11;
    Map.DimY = 5;
    Map.DisplayMap();
}
```

From what I learned, Segmentation faults happen when I try to access something I'm not supposed to. I don't know what it really means and how that happens in my code.

Comment: Nevermind, I found one way to solve it, I haven't used the Map::CellContent() function to create the vector board[i][j].

Comment: You're vectors already know how big they are.  Use that instead of DimX and DimY.

Comment: The segmentation error you get is probably caused by accessing an area outside the vector's memory range. You may not have set the dimensions of the vector correctly or you may be exceeding the boundaries of the vector when you try to access the elements.

Answer (score 1):

You are not calling `CellContent()` on your `Map` object to allocate and fill its `board` with data before then calling `DisplayMap()` to display the data, so its `board` is empty and your loops inside of `DisplayMap()` are exceeding `board`'s bounds, hence the segfault.

```
int main()
{
    Map Map;
    Map.DimX = 11;
    Map.DimY = 5;
    Map.CellContent(11, 5); // <-- add this!
    Map.DisplayMap();
}
```

That being said, it seems to me that `CellContent()` would be better off being a constructor instead, eg:

```
class Map
{
    vector<vector<char>> board;
    int DimX, DimY;

public:
    Map(int DimX, DimY);

    void DisplayMap() const;
    int getDimensions() const;
};

Map::Map(int DimX, int DimY)
    : DimX(DimX), DimY(DimY)
{
    // prepare board as needed...
}

void Map::DisplayMap() const
{
    // print board as needed...
}

int main()
{
    Map map(11, 5);
    map.DisplayMap();
}
```